# Cron error "missing url"

Tags: php, cron

Hope this is the correct place to post this. I am setting up a cron job to refresh a twitter feed. I want to overwrite the file each time the cron job executes. My current command is:

```
/usr/bin/wget -O "https://example.com/tweets.php"
```

However this produces the error

> wget: missing URL
>   Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

When i change this to

```
/usr/bin/wget "https://example.com/tweets.php"
```

I get a success message however it is not overwriting the original file i believe ?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: read the manual on what the `-O` parameter does

Comment: -O is an output file so wget treats your https://example.com/tweets.php as an argument to -O istead of URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-O` tells `wget` what to save the file as.  You didn't give it a filename.

```
wget -O tweets.txt https://example.com/tweets.php
```

DOCS: http://explainshell.com/explain/1/wget

Comment: Thanks, will do a bit more research in the docs before asking next time!